# How do I create citation call-outs and a formatted bibliography using biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

Suppose I have this book to reference:

```
    @article{serre1977linear,
  title={Linear representations of finite groups},
  author={Serre, Jean-Pierre},
  year={1977},
  publisher={Springer}
  }
```

in my document, how can do it using biblatex?

I tried the following;

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts, graphicx, verbatim, mathtools,amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{setspace}% if you must (for double spacing thesis)
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\usepackage[style=numeric,maxbibnames=99,sortcites=true,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\bibliography{groups & representations ref}

\begin{document}
A group is a set $G$ together with a binary operation $*$ on $G$ satisfying
the following properties:\cite{serre1977linear}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

(Of course this isn't the full document). But it didn't work. Can someone explain to me how biblatex should work briefly as well as solving my problem?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "it did not work". E.g., is biblatex complaining because you have `\addbibresource`, `\printbibliography`, *and* `\bibliography` directives? If it's something else, please be specific.

Comment: i'll provide all the code, so you can see what's going on

Comment: You do not provide standalone compilable code, but just a few code snippets. Incidentally, is there a bib file called `groups & representations.bib`?

Comment: no, its called groups & representations ref but this was saved as a latex file

Comment: I also have a file called groups & representations.bbl

Comment: Your edited code doesn't contain a `\cite` statement. Could that be the cause of problem? BTW, what are you trying to achieve by having both an `\addbibresource` and a `\bibliography` statement? Are your bib entries located in two separate files -- `References.bib` and `groups & representations.bib`?

Comment: does a '' \cite'' comment must be added? is it possible just to reference the book without citing it in certain places? and I removed addbibresource from my code. yes they are two separate files, let me attach a photo

Comment: If you have two separate bib files, you should provide two separate `\addbibresource` statements. If you don't provide any `\cite`-type instructions, you must at least provide a `\nocite{*}` instruction, to inform biblatex and bibtex that all entries in the bib files should be typeset.

Comment: I tried to use \cite{serre1977linear} and still its not working

Comment: I mean I have one file for all my references and one file for my 'proper' document.

Comment: so what shall I do?

Comment: It's well-nigh impossible to provide sensible, actionable advice if the only piece of diagnostic information is "it's still not working". *What exactly* isn't working? Do you get error and/or warning messages? If so, what do they say? What other pieces of information might be useful for detecting what's going on? Be as specific as you can. Incidentally, the screenshot you provided would be a whole lot more informative if it provided actual file name extensions for all rather than just a few selected files (.aux, .bbl, .run, and .gz).

Comment: I've never done referencing before hence I'm confused. I have done all the basics to get a bibliography but when I run the code I only get this in bold "/Serre1977linear/"

Comment: I also got an error when running my 'proper' document using bibtex saying "This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6350) The top-level auxiliary file: groups & representations.aux The style file: biblatex.bst White space in argument---line 3 of file groups & representations.aux : \bibdata{groups_&_representations-blx,groups : & representations ref} I'm skipping whatever remains of this command Database file #1: groups_&_representations-blx.bib Biblatex version: 3.3 (There was 1 error message)
Process exited with error(s)"

Comment: then when I run the document using "quick build" i'm getting the citation in bold "/Serre1977linear/" but no bibliography

Comment: For starters you should use better file names (without spaces, without special chars).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to make the following suggestions:

- Don't use a "fancy" file name -- meaning, *no embedded space characters* and *no TeX-special characters* such as `&` -- in the name of the tex file. Thus, rename the file `groups & representations.tex` to, say, `groups.tex`.
- Don't use a fancy file name for bib file either. `groups & representations ref.bib` is definitely asking for trouble. Something like `References.bib` or `groups.bib` will do just fine, though.
- If you want an entry contained in the bib file to show up in the formatted bibliography, you *must* `\cite` it at least once in the body of the document.
- Copy the code shown below into a test file called, say, `test.tex`.

  Aside: I changed the document class from `report` to `article` merely to allow both the numeric citation call-out and the formatted bibliography to be displayed on the same page.
- Then, run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more on the tex file. Ignore a complaint the very first time you run LaTeX. The complaint will go away after you've run BibTeX.

  You should get something very close to the following screenshot:

[image]

- If you had specified `backend=bibtex` instead of `backend=bibtex`, you would have to run biber rather than bibtex to generate the formatted bibliography.

Observe also that the entry type of the entry at hand should be `@book`, *not* `@article`. The latter entry type should be employed only for pieces published in scholarly journals. Observed that I back-filled the `address`, `series`, and `number` fields for the Serre entry -- your readers will likely appreciate you paying attention to such details.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{References.bib}
@book{serre1977linear,
  title   = {Linear Representations of Finite Groups},
  author  = {Serre, Jean-Pierre},
  year    = {1977},
  publisher={Springer},
  address = {Berlin},
  series  = {Graduate Texts in Mathematics},
  number  = 42,
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article} % or 'report'
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
%omitted packages that are irrelvant for example at hand

\usepackage[style=numeric,maxbibnames=99,sortcites=true,
            backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib}

\begin{document}
A group is a set $G$ together with a binary operation~$*$ 
on~$G$ satisfying the following properties: \cite{serre1977linear}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I will try it now :)

Comment: this is giving me errors?

Comment: the one thing I don't understand is, do I need to call the file groups.tex? or just groups as this will automatically save it as a tex file?

Comment: @john - Unless your editor has a setting that assigns the extension `.tex` if none is given explicitly, you should definitely provide the suffix yourself, i.e., call the file `groups.tex`.

Comment: @john - You also wrote, "this is giving me errors?" *Which errors*!? My psychic abilities are non-existent; if I'm not told what the error is about, chances that I will guess correctly what's going on are zero. Niente. Nada.

Comment: this is super frustrating

Comment: ok finally i have something :))

Comment: Took me some time, but I sorted it out (I think....) besides, I cannot thank you enough for your help pal :)

Comment: now i'm trying to do my second reference, its back to the same problem as before, i mean \diaconis1988groups\ pops up instead of "[2]" what is wrong?

Comment: aha I see. So we must run the bib file each time we add another entry then do the steps described above?

Comment: @john -- Each time you add new `\cite` instructions, you've got to first run LaTeX and the run BibTeX, followed by two more LaTeX runs. Conversely, if no new items are being `\cite`d, there's no need to rerun BibTeX.